# Is the difference between: Spin-orbit coupling and The Anomalous Zeeman effect only an external magnetic field?

Tags: quantum-spin, atomic-physics

I am having a hard time figuring out what the difference between spin-orbit coupling, fine structure, and the Anomalous Zeeman Effect is. As far as I have understood fine structure is just the over all theme including; The relativistic corrections to the Schrödinger equation (reletevistic mass, Darwin term, and spin orbit). And then the Anomalous Zeeman effect is just Spin-orbit coupling including an external magnetic field?

But I am very unsure about whether this is the correct way of thinking it.

Comment: Fine structure is reserved for quantum corrections due to relativistic effects only, and the Zeeman effect is the splitting of a spectral line due to an external magnetic field (and this is due to spin-orbit coupling). In non-relativistic quantum mechanics both effects are usually treated with perturbation theory.

Comment: Ahhh.... okay thanks for clearing out! 
But is spin orbit coupling seen as fine structure as well?

Comment: No, since it is not a relativistic effect.

Comment: Wait what: Spin-orbit-coupling *is* a relativistic effect. It follows from doing something like Foldy-Wouthuysen-trafo to the Dirac equation, which is a method to get relativistic corrections (in orders $1/c^n$). Spin-Orbit-Coupling is one of the main reasons for fine-structure. The dipole coupling of the electron spin to an external magnetic field (causing the Zeeman effect), however, occurs even at the lowest order of this expansion (so one might argue it is not relativistic, as it already occurs in order $1/c^0$).

Comment: Check if the spin number an even or odd multiple of 1/2.

Comment: Well, that is also how I understood it Sebastian. It also agrees with my textbook.